# handling multi client in game

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

i'm working on a game, the game has the server and the clients who connects to rooms to play,every room is a game, and is running on a thread,

now i thought about it and i know i'll need to communicate with all of the players during the game, i'm not sure how to do this, i thought about making a thread for each player which means i will need to open a thread for the room and 1-3 threads for the players!

for a mini-project it's fine yeah, but Theoretically if it was a game with million+ players, that means something like 1m minimum threads,

is it possible for a server to handle so many threads? and is it the right/an ok solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all would be extremely hard to synchronize and is a very expensive way of approaching this problem. It would be better to have one thread in which you handle all of the player processing, that way you don't have to worry about thread synchronization between the players. To be honest, if your game doesn't require a lot of processing time, you may be better of with a single thread design on which all the processing takes place rather than having to worry about everything being thread-safe. Obviously, this wouldn't be a favorable solution if you're trying to learn about multithreading.

Comment: but is it possible to handle a room(1-3 players) with one thread? i mean i need to read a socket for each player and i cant know the order the players will send data to me, and so far i have only seen sockets work in synchronous way.

Comment: @likesLowLevel well it certainly would be possible but it depends on how much processing one room takes up as to whether it is the most favorable solution. Games such as RuneScape are based on a single thread design as well and that server-client relation seems similar to what you're trying to achieve.